# A smooth function separating two disjoint closed subsets

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I'm trying this problem (2.14) in John M Lee's book on smooth manifolds:

> For any two disjoint closed sets $A$ and $B$ we can find a smooth function such that $f^{-1}(1)=A$ and $f^{-1}(0)=B$.

Can someone give a hint on how to do this?

I tried to use normality and partition of unity and the fact that for any closed set $K$ there is a smooth function $g$ such that $g^{-1}(0)=K$. But none of these seem to work.

Comment: If you can use Urysohn's lemma, it should be easy. If not, you can try to prove it and use it.

Comment: Urysohn lemma is for continuous functions, no?

Comment: Moreover I'm able to find a function such that $f$ restricted to $A$ is 1 and $f$ restricted to $B$ is 0.

Comment: @PrakharGupta How do you find that?

Comment: By normality, let $U$ and $V$ be disjoint open sets containing $A$ and $B$ respectively then  let W be an open set inside U such that closure of W is inside U. Then using bump functions on A and B we can find the required function. I'll give details in some time.

Comment: You can construct a smooth function using Urysohn's lemma and convolution product with a mollifier.

Comment: @nicomezi it is not clear how you still have $f^{-1}(1) = A$ after taking convolution?

Comment: @JohnMa You have to consider something a little larger than $A$ indeed. And take a mollifier with the right "thickness".